# How do I not save the QLineEdit input mask

Tags: python, pyqt

I am using an input mask on a QLineEdit with QT Designer. My mask looks like this HHH-HHH-HHHH. This works great for entering in a phone number except if a user does not enter a number because it is not a required field, the dashes still save. Also if they do enter a number, the dashes save also. I would like to have the mask for the user but strip it away before the data is saved.

Phone Entry

[image]

I have searched and can not find anything related to what I am needing.

Expected Save: 1234567890
Getting: 123-456-7890

Comment: can't you edit value before you save it ?

Comment: yes the value coming back should pass through a validation routine where things like 'HHH-HHH-HHHH' would be removed and/or recognized as a non-valid value further it should check for some known bad phone numbers such as ###-555-#### or any number that exceeds (high or low) the maximum limits currently in existence  Never just save raw data input by a user -- always always validate it to make sure its not garbage or hack-injection

Comment: Yes sorry, you can edit the data. The data is pulled from a Postgres table and also any changes are sent back. Thanks for everyones help. I will write a validation routine to remove anything unwanted prior to saving back to the table.